# md-to-pdf return timeout on a microservice on .NET Core

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core

When I use the md-to-pdf I get this timeout error:

> → waiting for Page.printToPDF failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded

This is the command that I am using:

```
md-to-pdf "README.md"
```

Checking the author's web site on github, I see a bug in status open:

https://github.com/simonhaenisch/md-to-pdf/issues/101

In this bug, an user say that the solution is:

> call here the setContent method passing the puppeteer options.
> call some of the set timeouts options
> https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/src/common/Page.ts#L917-L943

Does anyone understand the solution proposed by the user? Has anyone been able to fix this timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 solutions offered are simply two different ways to adjust the timeout to either extend it past 30 seconds or disable it entirely with a 0.

**First Solution**

> call here the [setContent](https://github.com/simonhaenisch/md-to-pdf/blob/3e45dc7634aa0cc5a7fb128b1836aea9613e6b6d/src/lib/generate-output.ts#L32) method passing the puppetteer
> [options](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/2b45027d256f85f21a0c824183696b237e00ad33/src/common/Page.ts#L1867) .

They're saying you can update the timeout value in the [options](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/2b45027d256f85f21a0c824183696b237e00ad33/src/common/Page.ts#L1867) parameter each time you call the [setContent](https://github.com/simonhaenisch/md-to-pdf/blob/3e45dc7634aa0cc5a7fb128b1836aea9613e6b6d/src/lib/generate-output.ts#L32) method.

**Second Solution**

> call some of the set timeouts options
> https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/src/common/Page.ts#L917-L943

You can also change a whole bunch of timeout values here on the [page object](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/2b45027d256f85f21a0c824183696b237e00ad33/src/common/Page.ts#L948) too.

Answer (score 1):

You can set timeout value by pdf_options in config json

For exsample...

```
$ cat config.json
{
  "pdf_options": {
    "timeout": "60000"
  }
}

$ md-to-pdf --config-file config.json README.md
```

I don't know why, but I couldn't use the --pdf-options option on the command line